# Bounding Boxes for Circle and Arcs in 3D

Tags: math, 3d, geometry

Given curves of type Circle and Circular-Arc in 3D space, what is a good way to compute accurate bounding boxes (world axis aligned)?

---

**Edit: found solution for circles, still need help with Arcs.**

C# snippet for solving BoundingBoxes for Circles:

```
public static BoundingBox CircleBBox(Circle circle)
{
  Point3d O = circle.Center;
  Vector3d N = circle.Normal;

  double ax = Angle(N, new Vector3d(1,0,0));
  double ay = Angle(N, new Vector3d(0,1,0));
  double az = Angle(N, new Vector3d(0,0,1));

  Vector3d R = new Vector3d(Math.Sin(ax), Math.Sin(ay), Math.Sin(az));
  R *= circle.Radius;

  return new BoundingBox(O - R, O + R);
}

private static double Angle(Vector3d A, Vector3d B)
{
  double dP = A * B;
  if (dP <= -1.0) { return Math.PI; }
  if (dP >= +1.0) { return 0.0; }

  return Math.Acos(dP);
}
```

Comment: What are you actually 'given' ?  A list of (x,y,z) triples representing the arcs as a series of straight lines ?  (Centre, radius, normal) with opening and closing angles for arcs ?  Parametric representations ?

Comment: I've got a parameteric definition of these. Circles are defined as a plane + radius (where plane is origin point, x-axis vector, y-axis vector & z-axis vector).

Arcs are defined as circles with an angle domain.

Comment: Looking at your Angle function, if A and B are not unit vectors you will likely get bad results.  It looks like you're using it properly in the code you posted.  But if you use it elsewhere, be careful.

Comment: The plane axis vectors are guaranteed to be unit vectors. If they weren't then a Vector3d.Unitize() must indeed be added.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing that's not specified is how you convert that angle range to points in space.  So we'll start there and assume that the angle 0 maps to **O** + r***X** and angle π/2 maps to **O** + r***Y**, where **O** is the center of the circle and 
**X** = (x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,x<sub>3</sub>)
 and
 **Y** = (y<sub>1</sub>,y<sub>2</sub>,y<sub>3</sub>) 
are unit vectors.

So the circle is swept out by the function

**P**(θ) = **O** + r*cos(θ)**X** + r*sin(θ)**Y**
where θ is in the closed interval [θ<sub>start</sub>,θ<sub>end</sub>].

The derivative of **P** is

**P**'(θ) = -r*sin(θ)**X** + r*cos(θ)**Y**

For the purpose of computing a bounding box we're interested in the points where one of the coordinates reaches an extremal value, hence points where one of the coordinates of **P**' is zero.

Setting -r*sin(θ)x<sub>i</sub> + r*cos(θ)y<sub>i</sub> = 0 we get
 tan(θ) = sin(θ)/cos(θ) = y<sub>i</sub>/x<sub>i</sub>.

So we're looking for θ where θ = arctan(y<sub>i</sub>/x<sub>i</sub>) for i in {1,2,3}.

You have to watch out for the details of the range of arctan(), and avoiding divide-by-zero, and that if θ is a solution then so is θ±k*π, and I'll leave those details to you.

All you have to do is find the set of θ corresponding to extremal values in your angle range, and compute the bounding box of their corresponding points on the circle, and you're done.  It's possible that there are no extremal values in the angle range, in which case you compute the bounding box of the points corresponding to θ<sub>start</sub> and θ<sub>end</sub>.  In fact you may as well initialize your solution set of θ's with those two values, so you don't have to special case it.